# How to remove unwanted spaces between the text in excel2007

Tags: excel-2007

I want to remove or delete the extra spaces in character value. For example the col contains the name data like:

```
"sachin sa meer pa war"
```

Actually i want this in one line with only 2 spaces like:

```
"sachin sameer pawar"
```

This will make me easy to text to col function.
So how can i remove those two unwanted spaces which is in between the middle name and in last name?

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically mention "those two unwanted spaces":

```
  =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A4," ","",2)," ","",3)
```